# powershell - create subfolders with MD and variable

Tags: powershell

I'm currently using this script to manage and sort some files.

I want to create a sub directory within the `$_.Name` directory labelled `2022`. How can I do that?

```bash
Get-ChildItem *_*_JDO_*_*.* |
  Where BaseName -match '\d{6}_\d{6}_JDO_(\d{4})_\d{3}'|
    Group {$Matches[1]}|
      ForEach{MD $_.Name;$_.Group|Move -Dest $_.Name}
```

Comment: do you want to receive filenames or directory names here? ```Get-ChildItem *_*_JDO_*_*.*``` You want to create a subfolder and move the files into that folder?

Comment: so the file name being worked with look similar to 210923_154527_JDO_8121_133.pdf. the script currently sorts them into folders based on the number after the JDO text in the file name. In this instance this file would go to .\8121\ I want it to go into .\8121\2022\

Answer (score 0):

```
#Get files - use parametr "-file" to only retrieve filenames
$files = Get-Childitem -file -filter '*_*_JDO_*_*.*' | ?{$_.baseName -match '\d{6}_\d{6}_JDO_(\d{4})_\d{3}'}
#Loop through array of files, get number after jdo_ and create subfolder [exctracted number]\2022, and move item to new subfolder
$files | %{
    #Get number from path
    $number = ($_.baseName -split '_')[3]
    #Create new target path
    $destination = new-item -ItemType Directory -Path (join-path -path $_.PSParentPath -childpath $number -additionalchildpath '2022') -Force
    #Move item
    $null = move-item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destination.FullName
}
```

Comment: had some issue with the additionalchildpath bit for some reason. I've butchered it and its working so thank you

Comment: $number = ($_.baseName -split '_')[3]
    $sub = "2022"
    #Create new target path
    $destination = new-item -ItemType Directory -Path (join-path -path $number -childpath $sub) -Force